# How to get default audio output

Tags: java, audio

I am writing a java program. It's going to be a game, I'm not quite sure of the details yet, but it will involve sound. I was wondering if there was a way in java to find the default system audio output device. I know how to find devices based on specifications, but I was wondering if there was a way to access the output that the user has set as default, because it doesn't really matter what specs they have but I don't want them to have to select the output if I can avoid it and I don't know what devices work or which ones they want. If I had access to the default audio I could bypass that entire process. I found another question asking something like this on stack overflow, but they didn't need a line, just access to whatever sound was coming out of the computer. It didn't have a any good answers, anyway. I have not found anything else related to this topic.

EDT: **I found a possible solution, and posted it below**. However, it uses midi audio instead
of sample audio, and if possible I would prefer a solution that uses sampled audio.

Comment: Take a look at [Accessing Audio System Resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html) and related trails

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I didn't find it before because it was really far into the Accessing Audio System Resources trail. It came way after everything else involving getting lines. Here is an excerpt:

"Obtaining Default Devices

A typical MIDI application program that uses the Java Sound API begins by obtaining the devices it needs, which can consist of one or more sequencers, synthesizers, input ports, or output ports.

There is a default synthesizer device, a default sequencer device, a default transmitting device, and a default receiving device. The latter two devices normally represent the MIDI input and output ports, respectively, if there are any available on the system. (It's easy to get confused about the directionality here. Think of the ports' transmission or reception in relation to the software, not in relation to any external physical devices connected to the physical ports. A MIDI input port transmits data from an external device to a Java Sound API Receiver, and likewise a MIDI output port receives data from a software object and relays the data to an external device.)

A simple application program might just use the default instead of exploring all the installed devices. The MidiSystem class includes the following methods for retrieving default resources:

```
static Sequencer getSequencer()
static Synthesizer getSynthesizer()
static Receiver getReceiver()
static Transmitter getTransmitter()
```

The first two of these methods obtain the system's default sequencing and synthesis resources, which either represent physical devices or are implemented wholly in software. The getReceiver method obtains a Receiver object that takes MIDI messages sent to it and relays them to the default receiving device. Similarly, the getTransmitter method obtains a Transmitter object that can send MIDI messages to some receiver on behalf of the default transmitting device."

So basically you would use

```
MidiSystem.getTransmitter();
```

to get the default output and

```
MidiSystem.getReceiver();
```

to get the default input.